# Where do I put the Creative Commons license information in a book?

Tags: copyright, online-publication, creative-commons

We're about to publish a book (conference proceedings) as a PDF online and want to license it under Creative Commons. Before each article, we're giving out information for citing the following article like so:
*author, article-title, book-title, publishing-place year, page x–y.*

I think it would be best to put the information about the Creative Commons license (in our case CC BY-ND) after this line – what do you think?
Also, I guess it would be a good idea to provide a link to further information about the CC.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to replace the abbreviation in your question title to the full form - hope you agree with this change. When I first saw the question (without looking at the tags because I was lazy ... but it could *really*, *justifiably* happen if the question makes it to the hot questions list, or if it appears in the related or linked questions for any other question) I thought this was referring to the CC field in e-mails, so I was slightly confused when reading it at first.

Comment: Oh – right! Thank you, haven't thought about this possibility of confusion.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about academia.

Comment: I am unclear about your question. 1. What is your book about? 2. "_Before each text we're giving out information for citing the following text_" What do you mean by **text**? Chapter? Page? Line?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: I am glad you didn't suspect the OP of wanting to publish their credit card information in their book :)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I've submitted an edit to your edit (how circular...) to clarify it's referring to  the license information rather than a mark (image, logo, etc) - the answer would probably be slightly different for each case.

Comment: @scaaahu It's conference proceedings, therefore there are 10 articles by 10 different people in this book. The information about citing and CC is placed before each article.

Comment: Related new SE site (where Creative Commons questions are on-topic): [opensource.se]

Comment: @unor thanks for the link! Is it possible to relocate my question to this other SE-site by a moderator?

Comment: @unor I'm not sure relocating would be appropriate - open access/open licensing is not quite the same thing as open source, and the question is now pretty clear it's talking about scholarly publication.

Answer (score 4):

This is a good approach. It's helpful to have the license on each "unit" - so if you're putting it up as separate chapters, have a license statement on each chapter. Putting it with the citation is sensible, but make sure it's on a seperate line so it's not seen as *part* of the citation.

Something like "This chapter is available under the Creative Commons Attribution-No Derivatives license [version]" is good. It should include a link to the license code if possible - otherwise it's not much help if someone doesn't know what the license is!

If the entire book is in a single PDF, or if you have the "front matter" as a seperate PDF, you could put the license + link on the copyright page (reverse of the title page), and it's often common to have a license logo on the (back?) cover as well.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and the suggestions I think I'll realise all of them.
We're planning on putting the whole book to a single pdf but you never know with pdfs, you can easily split them plus: who reads the imprint..But I'd rather not put the logo anywhere.